# glib g main loop callback called more than one time without reason

Tags: c, glib

I want to have a process with it g_main_loop that call a callback on incoming character within a file descriptor.

So I try with the above code on my board with the `/home/dev` file manually create.

Without doing something more than launching this code, callback is continuelly call.

I don't understand why. I expected callback to be call only if I write within `/home/dev` file. Is it an `f_open` file option issue ? Or am I not doing the right thing for the file descriptor considers data as read ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

gboolean cb_1 (GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data);

int main(void)
{
  GMainLoop* mainloop;
  int fd;
  GIOChannel* channel;

  mainloop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, TRUE);

  fd=g_open("/home/dev", O_RDONLY, O_NONBLOCK);

  channel=g_io_channel_unix_new(fd);

  g_io_add_watch(channel, G_IO_IN, cb_1, NULL);

  g_main_loop_run(mainloop);

  g_main_loop_unref(mainloop);
}

gboolean cb_1 (GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data)
{
  gchar** line=NULL;
  GIOStatus status;
  GError* error;

  printf("cb\n");    

  status=g_io_channel_read_line(source, line, NULL, NULL, &error);

  if(G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL == status)
  {
    printf("callback : data : %s\n", *line);
    g_free(*line);
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a file and creating a channel will trigger your callback whenever file is available to read.

In Linux, you need inotify watchers to achieve what you want. Below is the code snippet which helps you to understand it. In the callback method you need to read struct inotify_event to know the event for which your callback is called. Read inotify man page for complete details on possible mask that you can use. You may also need flags like IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

GMainLoop *mainloop;

static gboolean inotify_data(GIOChannel * channel, GIOCondition cond, gpointer user_data)
{
     printf("event on GIOChannel\n");
     char buffer[256];
     gsize bytes_read;

     GIOStatus status = g_io_channel_read_chars(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &bytes_read, NULL);

     /* buffer can have multiple inotify_event structs which contains
      * details of what event, which file triggered this callback.
      */
     return TRUE;
}

int main(void)
{
     int fd, wd;
     GIOChannel *channel;

     mainloop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

     fd = inotify_init();
     if (fd < 0) {
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/test", IN_OPEN | IN_MODIFY);

    channel = g_io_channel_unix_new(fd);
    if (!channel) {
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    g_io_channel_set_close_on_unref(channel, TRUE);
    g_io_channel_set_encoding(channel, NULL, NULL);
    g_io_channel_set_buffered(channel, FALSE);

    g_io_add_watch(channel, G_IO_IN | G_IO_HUP | G_IO_NVAL | G_IO_ERR, inotify_data, NULL);

    g_main_loop_run(mainloop);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Ravi, but unfortunately it does not work for me. When I write within file callback isn't call. I read man page of inotify functions family but I don't understand where is the problem...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, your solution works. Thanks for this !